# The template style option is missing from all menu items

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, administrator

We have a weird problem where at some point our menu styles dropdown has disappeared from all menu items.  We can see it in our old site, and we're pretty sure it used to be there, and we're not really sure when it disappeared or how to get it back.  We can change it in our template by assigning it, so that's helpful, but for one page it's not working and we wondered if this was the reason.

In any case, we want our Joomla! working properly.

I have checked Admin Template Overrides there are none for menu items.
I have used Joomla to reinstall Joomla using the Joomla updater.

[image: Missing Teamplte Style Option]

[image: With the Template Style option]

Comment: Can you open your browser inspector and search for `template_style_id` to see if it's hidden or actually non-existant?

Comment: From what I can see, this parameter only gets hidden if the menu type is `alias`, or if `alias_redirect` is set to `0`

Comment: Weirdly it's on all menus that we've checked.

Comment: I can confirm it is not hidden, it is not there at all

Comment: Can also confirm no admin menu template overrides

Comment: Notes for myself.  Could some plugin be removing it?  Could some JavaScript be removing it?  Search backend Network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah ha we uninstalled Regular Labs Advanced Template Manager which solved the problem.  Clearly it takes control of the templates so that makes sense.